# How to get last record group by join query in two table

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

Here is my modal query

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(n.status='0',1, NULL)) as counter, n.notify_from, n.notify_to,  n.status, n.notify_text, n.notify_id, n.notify_type, n.notify_time, r.user_name, r.user_image, r.user_gender FROM `notifications` AS n JOIN register r ON n.`notify_from` = r.unique_user_name WHERE n.`notify_to` = 'IzaazG' AND n.`notify_type` = '6' GROUP BY n.`notify_from` ORDER BY n.`notify_id` DESC
```

From this query i am unable to get the last records from notification table.

Comment: What do you mean by "last"? What are you getting as a result versus what you want to get? What do you mean by "modal query"?

Comment: I am using codeigniter, that why i have used the word modal,, 2nd is last record means that i can't get MAX id of notification table..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the IF condition from the function COUNT 
 and try to use a case statement

Comment: I have used with * , same result given by query.

Comment: n.notify_from, n.notify_to, 
 n.status, n.notify_text, 
 n.notify_id, n.notify_type, n.notify_time, 
 r.user_name, r.user_image, r.user_gender 
Please put this columns in the group by
Do not include  the count

Comment: @AizazGull If I understant it right : You are trying to get the number of notif from the column notify_from? If you want only the number it is not necesary to put all the column in the select . you only need the function there and if you want to show the text of the column you are grouping  put that column in the select too. But remember that every column that is in the select statement should also  be on the group by except the aggregate function . Count in your case

Comment: If you want the second try it this way
_______
 with cte(max,nr) as (  select n.notify_from, n.notify_to, 
 n.status, n.notify_text, 
 n.notify_id, n.notify_type, n.notify_time, 
 r.user_name, r.user_image, r.user_gender ,ROW_NUMBER()over (order by n.`notify_id` desc)
FROM `notifications` AS n 
 JOIN register r ON n.`notify_from` = r.unique_user_name
  WHERE n.`notify_to` = 'IzaazG' AND n.`notify_type` = '6' 

)
 select * from cte where nr = 2